# Can I use 250μF capacitor instead of 100μF?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

I am trying to drive a stepper motor from an old DVD drive with the Pololu A4988 driver and an Arduino. The **[data sheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/download/A4988.pdf?file_id=0J450)** says I need a 100μF capacitor to prevent voltage spikes when using a 12V PSU (I'm using a PSU from an external hard drive enclosure, 12V 2A). I don't have any capacitors laying around and I see there are some 250μF capacitors on the board of the DVD drive that I took the stepper motor out of. Can I safely use the 250μF capacitor instead of the 100μF capacitor?

Comment: That's not a datasheet, it's a product description page on a web shopping site. This said, I see no problem in using a 250uF cap, provided it is rated at 15V or more.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the link. Oh I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll further down on the page, there is a section **Power connections**:

> Warning: This carrier board uses low-ESR ceramic capacitors, which makes it susceptible to destructive LC voltage spikes, especially when using power leads longer than a few inches. Under the right conditions, these spikes can exceed the 35 V maximum voltage rating for the A4988 and permanently damage the board, even when the motor supply voltage is as low as 12 V. One way to protect the driver from such spikes is to put a large (at least 47 µF) electrolytic capacitor across motor power (VMOT) and ground somewhere close to the board.

As you can see, it says an at least 47uF so there won't be problem with a 250uF.

Unfortunately the AN4988's datasheet does not have much information about this capacitor, but it should be rated at least on 35V as the max load voltage is 35V. But it is always safer (see the warning about the voltage spikes > 35V) to choose a little bit bigger one, so I would recommend a capacitor rated on at least 50V. On other designs of this chip, an 50V capacitor is used:

[image]

On this board there is an 47uF, 50V SMD aluminim capacitor.

Comment: Great, thank you! I just started with electronics a few days ago so i'm still learning the basics! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Mention the voltage rating of the capacitors, and I'll upvote this answer.

Comment: I see it says "250uf 16V". I also see others with 220uf 16V

Comment: @Bruno: Sorry, that was meant for Bence Kaulics.  The voltage ratings of the capacitors is an important part of deciding whether or not the capacitors are usable, and belongs in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

This resistor is used to prevent voltage spikes and the datasheet recommends a capacitor of 100uF because the spike contains a certain amount of charge which can be stored across the capacitor and delay the increase of voltage across its terminals effectively removing the "spike". Having a higher capacitor is okay and is not a disadvantage in your case.

**Make sure your 250uF capacitors voltages are higher or at least equal to the 100uF capacitors recommended voltages.**

The working science is based on the fact that voltage across a capacitor never changes at once. it changes gradually. because of this, we have a way to stop these "sudden" or "spike" increments across a component if we fix a capacitor across it. You may refer wikipedia for further understanding.